# log4j2 TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy occurs only after logs are updated?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 yaml configuration for writing logs in my application below is my yaml configuration file

```
  Configutation:
  name: Default
  Properties:
    Property:
      - name: application-log
        value: logs/      
      - name: archive
        value: ${application-log}/archive
  Appenders:
    File:
      name: FileAppender
      fileName: ${application-log}/application.log
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%level] [%logger{36}] - %msg%n"
    RollingFile:
      - name: transaction_file_appender
        fileName: ${application-log}/transaction.log
        filePattern: ${archive}/transaction_%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log.gz
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "%msg%n"
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 5 KB
          TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            interval: 1
        DefaultRollOverStrategy:
          max: 30
      - name: backend_file_appender
        fileName: ${application-log}/backend.log
        filePattern: ${archive}/backend_%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log.gz
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "%msg%n"
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 5 KB
        DefaultRollOverStrategy:  
          max: 10
  Loggers:
      Root:
        level: info
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: FileAppender
      Logger:
        -
          name: transaction_logger
          level: debug
          additivity: 'false'
          appender-ref:
            level: debug
            ref: transaction_file_appender
        -
          name: backend_logger
          level: debug
          additivity: 'false'
          appender-ref:
            level: debug
            ref: backend_file_appender
```

In this configuration I have created 2 rolling file appenders for transaction and backend. and have added SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy and TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy. SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy  is working as expected butTimeBasedTriggeringPolicy is not rotating file after specified time.
As per documentation mentioned [HERE](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender)

---

**a rollover should occur based on the most specific time unit in the date pattern. For example, with a date pattern with hours as the most specific item and and increment of 4 rollovers would occur every 4 hours. The default value is 1.**

In my case I have given file pattern %d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm} which means it should rotate every minute. But it is not rotating every minute if system is idle (I mean no logs are written) It is rotating only when some event happens. Does it mean TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy occurs only after logs are updated ? 
I want to rotate it every min/hour irrespective of whether logs/event happens or not ?
does CronTriggeringPolicy rotate without events ?